# ¿Como llamar un array creado en main desde una clase?

Tags: java, array, class

Como puedo llamar desde una clase un array creado en main, inicialmente los array estaban definidos, pero tuve que modificar el código para ingresar los valores del array, al no poder hacerlo directo en la clase con Scanner estuve probando y finalmente pude hacerlo desde main, pero ahora no se como llamar los array para que el programa se pueda ejecutar, espero haberme explicado bien. Soy nuevo en Java y no se si sea la mejor forma para ajustar el código, el código original lo tome de https://censorcosmico.blogspot.com/2016/05/problema-del-viajante-de-comercio-tsp.html

```
(Ruta.java)
    package Tsp;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Ruta {
        public static <Principal> void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Cuantas ciudades vistaras: ");//Solicitar cantidad de ciudades
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = reader.nextInt(), x1 = x;

    String[] nombre_nodos = new String[x];
    Scanner nodo_x = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0; i<nombre_nodos.length; i++){
        System.out.printf("Introduzca ciudad a visitar: ", i+1);
        nombre_nodos[i] = nodo_x.nextLine();
    }

(Principal.java)
    package Tsp;

    import java.util.*;

    public class Principal {

        String[] nombre_nodos = new nombre_nodos();
        Double[] coordenadasX = new coordenadasX();
        Double[] coordenadasY = new coordenadasY();
        List<String> lista_nombre_nodos = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> lista_coordenadasX = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> lista_coordenadasY = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varias cosas a tener en cuenta, el método main es TODO lo que hace la aplicación cuando se ejecuta, es decir, comienza y termina, una vez acaba el método main, la aplicación termina, por lo tanto si lo que quieres es meter el array ese que has creado en la clase Principal se haría de la siguiente manera:

**Definición de la clase `Principal`**

La clase `Principal` está mal definida, pues no creo que tengas ninguna clase llamada `nombre_nodos` ni `coordenadasX` ni `coordenadasY`, pues no las has puesto en la pregunta... entonces vamos a definirla bien:

```
package Tsp;

import java.util.*;

public class Principal {
    
    // Varias cosas aquí
    // 1-Si inicializas las cosas en esta parte de la clase, 
    // le estas metiendo ya valores por defecto que seguro que vas
    // a sobrescribir en algun momento, Java ya pone valores
    // por defecto

    // 2- No sé por qué mezclas List con Arrays normales, declara todo como List
    String[] nombre_nodos;
    Double[] coordenadasX;
    Double[] coordenadasY;
    List<String> lista_nombre_nodos;
    List<Double> lista_coordenadasX;
    List<Double> lista_coordenadasY;

    // Constructora
    // Aquí se les ponen valore por defecto a los valores, 
    // para cuando hagas new Principal, se inicialicen
    public Principal(){
        // nombre de atributos con formato CamelCase, 
        // en lugar de nombre_nodos, pon nombreNodos, esto es java
        nombre_nodos=null;
        coordenadasX=null;
        coordenadasY=null;
        // No entiendo estos atributos, pero te los mantengo
        // igual los necesitas
        lista_nombre_nodos=new ArrayList<String>();
        lista_coordenadasX=new ArrayList<Double>();
        lista_coordenadasY=new ArrayList<Double>();           
    }
// Getters y setter, si usas eclipse, pestaña source y generate getters y setters, te los crea todos, sino... genéralos tú
```

**El método `main()`**

```
public static <Principal> void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Cuantas ciudades vistaras: ");//Solicitar cantidad de ciudades
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = reader.nextInt(), x1 = x;

    String[] nombre_nodos = new String[x];
    Scanner nodo_x = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0; i<nombre_nodos.length; i++){
        System.out.printf("Introduzca ciudad a visitar: ", i+1);
        nombre_nodos[i] = nodo_x.nextLine();
    }
    Principal principal = new Principal();
    principal.setNombre_nodos(nombre_nodos);

    // Ya está, aquí principal tiene el array dentro, recuerda renombrar todo con formato CamelCase, es decir, nombreVariable en lugar de nombre_variable
}
```